# if div with id has certain text remove other div • Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i've got several divs like these:

```
<div id="404.4T:"></div>
<div id="404.4R:"></div>
<div id="404.4P:"></div>
<div id="404.4B:"></div>
```

I need using javascript to show only div with letter T and hide the other and so on ... I've got 4 buttons and each show the divs with le letter selected...
I found this code:

```
function myFunction0() { 
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = divs.length; i;) {
        var div = divs[--i];
        if (div.id.indexOf("P:") > -1) {
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        }
    }
}
```

It works but i can't show divs with P again.
Thanks Davide.

Comment: You can't show them again because you're removing them from the DOM. You'll need to alter the CSS - perhaps by adding a class - to hide them instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your removed them from the page, you should change their `display` css propertie for `none` so it will just hide them. You can then show them back by changing the css property `display` to `block again.

```
<div id="404.4T:"></div>
<div id="404.4R:"></div>
<div id="404.4P:"></div>
<div id="404.4B:"></div>
<script>
function myFunction0() {
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = divs.length; i;) {
    var div = divs[--i];
    if (div.id.indexOf("P:") > -1) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}}
</script>
```

And then you can switch them back on using

```
div.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must hide the div instead of remove.

```
// This for hide
element.style.display= "none";
// This to display
element.style.display= "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the elements from the page; they no longer exist. Change this line:

`div.parentNode.removeChild(div);`

to:

```
// hide, but don't remove, the element
div.style.display = 'none';
```

and then use this to show the div again:

```
// show the element again
div.style.display = 'block';
```

alternatively, you can try the `visibility` property if you need the element to continue to take up space on the page, but not be showing. Use `hidden` to hide, and `visible` to show.